# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sqrt[n]{a}-1)$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given $a>1$, establish whether the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sqrt[n]{a}-1\right)$$ converges or diverges.

I think that it diverges. I want to expand $\sqrt[n]{a}-1$ using Taylor around $0$ but I don't see how to do it.

Comment: What are the conditions on $a$?

Comment: $$\sqrt[n]{a}-1 = \exp(\frac 1n \ln a) - 1 \sim \frac{\ln a}n $$

Comment: $a>1$ sorry i forgot to write it

Comment: @GabrielRomon you use Taylor around which point?

Comment: $e^x = 1+x +o_0(x)$, yeah ?

Comment: @spyer Taylor series of $\exp$ around $0$, as $n\to\infty$. You can also see it as a derivative...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\sqrt[n]{a}-1=e^{\frac{\log a}{n}}-1\sim\frac{\log a}{n}$$

thus the series diverges by [limit comparison test](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/SeriesTests/limit_comparison.html) with $\sum\frac{1}{n}$.

or as an alternative by Bernoulli

$$\sqrt[n]{a}-1=\sqrt[n]{1+c}-1>1+ \frac c n-1=\frac c n$$

and then the series diverges also by comparison with $\sum\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Why this is true? How can I conclude this?

Comment: @spyer by limit comparison test, I add a link for that

Comment: @spyer refer to https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/SeriesTests/limit_comparison.html

Comment: @spyer it is a very powerful test for series since you can avoid to use inequality which are elegant but more difficult to find out or prove

Comment: @gimusi yes, that's the power of **asymptotic** calculus.

Comment: The first equation is false: as pointed out in @GabrielRomon's comment, $\sqrt[n]{a}-1\sim \frac{\log{a}}{n}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Holographer Yes of course you are absolutely right. Thanks to have pointed it out! I fix

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{a}-1)=\ln a$$ thus the series diverges by comparison with $\sum\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $c>d>0$ we have
$$ c^n-d^n \leq n(c-d)c^{n-1},\qquad c-d\geq\frac{c^n-d^n}{n c^{n-1}} $$
hence by assuming $a>1$ and by letting $c=\sqrt[n]{a}, d=1$ we get
$$ \sqrt[n]{a}-1 \geq \frac{a-1}{n a^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}\geq\left(1-\frac{1}{a}\right)\frac{1}{n} $$
hence the given series is divergent by comparison with the harmonic series.